# Difference between $var === 1 and $var === TRUE in PHP

Tags: php, boolean, conditional-statements

While reviewing a pull request, I noticed my colleague is using a lot of truthy checks in the following manner:

```
if ($var === 1)
```

This doesn't work as expected for one condition in particular:

```
if(!empty($myArr) === 1) {  } //
```

I know this won't work as expected in javascript, upon consulting [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), I am not 100% sure if this would work properly in PHP either.

My question is, would this work OK in PHP? Which one is a better way of checking for comparisons?
 `true` or `1`

Using php 7.2

Comment: Depends on what you actually want... the "===" operator checks if value _and type_ equal. So a boolean value _can never equal_ a number using that operator. Why can't you simply use the simple variant for your example: `if (!empty($myArr)) {...}` ?

Comment: `$var === 1` means `$var` is an **integer** equal to `1`. `$var === true` means `$var` is a **boolean** equal to `true`. They are not the same, and as you have seen, are not interchangeable in PHP either.

Comment: Gotchya @Nick that's what my understanding was but the code I am reviewing is from a much 'senior' developer in title so I was a bit confused for a moment.

Comment: @Anon just goes to show `"senior" !== "smarter"` :-)